# how to select certain parts of an object to render to the Dom with react and Material UI

Tags: reactjs, object, material-ui

[image: object image I want to render part of]

I have this object above, it's an array of Objects really, I have mapped over the array as so

```
 <TableBody>
              {union &&
                unionArray.map((row) => (
                  <TableRow key={row.name}>
                    <TableCell component="th" scope="row">
                      {row.name}
                    </TableCell>
                    <TableCell align="center">{????????}</TableCell>
                  </TableRow>
                ))}
            </TableBody>
```

in a material UI table. I want to render the other parts of the object apart from the name which I have rendered in the first cell, in the Table cell. it's tricky for me since they have different keys (a,b,c d,e) I want to render both those keys and their values - as in
row1: obj1     a  1

Comment: are you trying to put those key/values into a single table cell?

Comment: yeah eventually I'd use a drop down, but for now, I just want to put them in a single table cell, the other cell being the object name

Answer (score 1):

If you want to display `name` in its own cell, while dumping the rest of the key/value pairs into another cell, you should do something like this ([Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vigorous-khayyam-fq6pq?file=/src/App.js)):

```
const ar = [
  { name: "Some Name 1", a: 1 },
  { name: "Some Name 2", a: 1, b: 3, c: 5 },
  { name: "Some Name 3", c: 4 },
  { name: "Some Name 4", a: 5, w: 34 }
];

export default function App() {
  const CombinedTD = ({ row }) => {
    const values = Object.keys(row).map((key) => {
      let str = "";
      if (key !== "name") str = `${key}:${row[key]}`;
      return str;
    });

    return <span>{values.join().slice(1)}</span>;
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <table>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Other stuff</th>
          </tr>
          {ar.map((row, i) => (
            <tr key={i}>
              <td>{row.name}</td>
              <td>
                <CombinedTD row={row} />
              </td>
            </tr>
          ))}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Obviously I am using a regular table here as opposed to a MUI table, but it will work the same exact way.

Comment: thanks for the pointers, they were super helpful

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you to try something like that:

```
<TableBody>
  {union &&
    unionArray.map((row) => (
      <TableRow key={row.name}>
      { Object.keys(row).map(key => (
        <TableCell component="th" scope="row">
          {key} {row[key]}
        </TableCell>
      ) }
      </TableRow>
   ))}
</TableBody>
```